# Why doesn't this use of Elem typecheck?

Tags: idris

I am quite confused.

```
module Experiment

import Data.Vect

p1: Elem 5 [3,4,5,6]
p1 = There (There Here)

v : Vect 4 Int
v = 3 :: 4 :: 5 :: 6 :: Nil

p2: Elem 5 v
p2 = There (There Here)
```

The definition of `p2` does not typecheck, while the definition of `p1` does. I am using Idris 0.10.2. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lowercase names in type declarations are interpreted as implicit arguments (like `a` in `length : List a -> Nat` which is actually `length : {a : Type} -> List a -> Nat`). To refer to the defined `Vect` you can either use an uppercase name or refer by the namespace:

```
module Experiment

import Data.Vect

A : Vect 4 Int
A = 3 :: 4 :: 5 :: 6 :: Nil

p2: Elem 5 A
p2 = There (There Here)

a : Vect 4 Int
a = 3 :: 4 :: 5 :: 6 :: Nil

p3: Elem 5 Experiment.a
p3 = There (There Here)
```

Comment: Thanks! I should have known. Here is the relevant phrase from the Idris tutorial: _Any name beginning with a lower case letter which appears as a parameter or index in a type declaration, which is not applied to any arguments, will always be automatically bound as an implicit argument._